# PID full path to executable in macOS Mojave

Tags: osx, ps

> ps axww -o command

This command gives me the "command" used to run the process. It also includes the "path" to the executable. I need ONLY the path. The problem is it also includes arguments with the path. I don't want the arguments.

example without args (This one is good)

> /Applications/Calculator.app/Contents/MacOS/Calculator

example with args (This one isn't because it has --type=utility at the end)

> /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/Versions/**.*.****.***/Google
>   Chrome Helper.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome Helper --type=utility

I know I can use | cut to cut the args like this

> ps axww -o command | cut -f1 -d"-"

But now I'm having to add a ton of cuts to keep up with all the different switches on the different commands.

example

> ps axww -o command | cut -f1 -d"-" | cut -f1 -d"("

and so on. Is there a way to get the full file path of all currently running processes and not this hack of showing the "command" which just happens to include the path?

Comment: ucomm just gives me the name of the process, not its location.

Comment: Yes ps -ax -o comm gives me a list of all process names but not their full path location. ps -ax -o comm is also truncated to 16 characters from some reason.

Comment: Im on mojave also.

Comment: Will `ps -ewwo comm` work for you?

Comment: That's it! Thank you!. I can't believe it was that easy. If you want to put it in the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So on MacOS X this command works great. This was provided by @fd0

> ps -ewwo comm

Comment: Note that this just returns `argv[0]` of the process, which does not have to be the full path of the executable.  For example, `ps -ewwo comm= $$` will usually print `-bash`, etc.